# Transpose rows into columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot

How can I convert rows into columns in a MySQL query?

Comment: Depending upon what exactly you need you might need to use a `PIVOT` technique. In MySQL there is no inbuilt support so you need to use `CASE` statements. Can you provide a small example of source data and desired results?

Comment: for example , i am having a resultset with one col and 18 rows . how to convert them into 18 cols and 1 row

Comment: Right sounds like you are looking to transpose the whole thing. Pivot wouldn't do this.

Comment: This looks relevant, not sure if it's exactly a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187460/sql-rows-to-columns

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can turn rows into *a* column with `GROUP_CONCAT`, but you can't transpose whole result sets in any automatic way. You either write a query that produces each column manually, or you do it in an application.

Here's a tutorial on writing the complicated queries to emulate the transposition:

http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78