# Insert each column of one table as a row in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table with the following columns:

```
c1, c2, c3, c4, c5
```

And another table with the following columns:

```
id, column_info
```

...there are some other columns but here's the main problem.

For each column in table 1, I'd like to insert a row in table 2, like this:

```
id | column_info
---|------------
 1 | c1
 2 | c2
 3 | c3
 4 | c4
 5 | c5
```

Is this possible as an SQL statement?

Comment: You want to do this with pure SQL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transpose rows into columns in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943496/transpose-rows-into-columns-in-mysql)

Comment: @alex it would be awesome. I'm already working on a PHP script, but it would be nice for the learning to find out if it's possible and how to do it.

Comment: @eduffy not quite. I'm going the other way. from Columns to rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Some_Table (id, column_info)
SELECT id, c1 UNION ALL
SELECT id, c2 UNION ALL
SELECT id, c3 UNION ALL
SELECT id, c4 UNION ALL
SELECT id, c5
```