# Tricky MySQL query instead of a Python script to achieve the result?

Tags: python, mysql, pivot, report, transpose

Before I set out to write a Python script, I want to see if MySQL alone can produce the result.

I have a list of products :

```
PID Product 
-----------
1   AAA
2   ABC
3   BAC
4   CAB
5   CBA
```

I have a list of companies ordering these products several times :

```
CID PID
-------
1   1
2   3
1   5
3   2
1   1
2   3
```

The desired result :

```
CID AAA ABC BAC CAB CAB CBA
---------------------------
1   Y                   Y
2           Y
3       Y
```

How I would do this in Python?

- Create a temp table with columns (CID AAA ABC BAC CAB CAB CBA)
- Run 2 loops and update the desired table when the desired column matches.

Just curious to see if there exists a MySQL only solution.

p.s : This is just a sample and the actual problem has few 100 products and few 1000 companies. I created a temp table for 100 products by doing a transpose in Excel and converted it to a MySQL table.

**Following is the approach I finally resorted to. Thanks for the feedback guys.**

```
########### Python script to generate the MySQL query ##############

#MySQL Connection String Goes here#

#Generate MySQL 'CASE' logic

cursor = db.cursor()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    cursor.execute("select PID, Product from products")
    productlist = cursor.fetchall()

    for product in productlist:
        print ("max(case when PID = %s then 'Y' else '' end) as `%s`,") % (product[0], product[1])

db.close()
```

Use the generated query in the format as suggested by nick.

```
select cid,
max(case when pid = 1 then 'Y' else '' end) as AAA,
max(case when pid = 2 then 'Y' else '' end) as ABC,
max(case when pid = 3 then 'Y' else '' end) as BAC,
max(case when pid = 4 then 'Y' else '' end) as CAB,
max(case when pid = 5 then 'Y' else '' end) as CBA
from companies
group by cid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select cid,
max(case when pid = 1 then 'Y' else '' end) as AAA,
max(case when pid = 2 then 'Y' else '' end) as ABC,
max(case when pid = 3 then 'Y' else '' end) as BAC,
max(case when pid = 4 then 'Y' else '' end) as CAB,
max(case when pid = 5 then 'Y' else '' end) as CBA
from companies
group by cid
```

Comment: I like this so far but so many case statements if I have 100 products!

Comment: Handle your output with a script. I don't know other alternative to this query. You could automate it with a stored procedure but the code will be always the same. :)

Answer (score 2):

What the other answers seem to be dancing around is the fact that, for a large amount of products, there is no practical way to do this in MySQL alone.

See the answer to this question: [Transpose rows into columns in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943496/transpose-rows-into-columns-in-mysql)

So the answer to your question is probably: go ahead and write that Python script.

Comment: Yep, Python script it is. Updated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have duplicate data? Twice, there's a 1 1 and a 2 3.

I don't understand the desire to represent data in this way. If it's to represent on your UI, it's a bad idea. Stick with python I say and do it in one loop:
1) create table
2) fetch data
3) foreach result in resultset of select cid, pid ... mark table with 'Y'

Comment: This is for reporting purposes. Not a UI or anything else, just a spreadsheet!

Answer (score 0):

This will get you all results concatenated into only 1 column instead of 5 (or 100):

```
SELECT
    o.CID
  , GROUP_CONCAT( CASE WHEN d.dummy IS NOT NULL 
                       THEN ' Y '
                       ELSE '   '
                  END 
                  ORDER BY p.Product
                  SEPARATOR ' '
                ) AS Products
FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT 
          CID
      FROM Ordering
    ) AS c
  CROSS JOIN 
    Product p
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 1 AS dummy) AS d
      ON EXISTS
         ( SELECT *
           FROM Ordering AS o
           WHERE o.PID = p.PID
             AND o.CID = c.CID
         )
GROUP BY c.CID
```

If however, you have 100 products and 10K companies, it may be slow as hell.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not so sure about your desired result, but it is rather easy to create something similar in MySQL usind `GROUP BY`, which might make it easier to create the desired view in Python:

```
SELECT orders.cid, products.product
FROM orders, products
WHERE orders.pid=products.pid
GROUP BY products.product
```

Comment: I have few 100 columns and I don't want to do something like this.

Comment: Why not, what is the problem?

Comment: It will be tedious trying to get the desired output with 100 columns, don't you think? I want to display 100 columns from left to right, this query spits out 2 columns?

Comment: I updated my answer to include the missing "in Python". I think, a grouping query gives you a simple data structure to build your view from.