# something like "group by" for columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have table like this:

```
+----+---------+---------+--------+
| id | value_x | created | amount |
+----+---------+---------+--------+
```

value_x is set of six strings, lets say "one", "two", "three", etc.
I need to create report like this:

```
+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------+----------------------+
| day_of_month |          "one"          |      "two"        |          [etc.]      |
+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------+----------------------+
|  01-01-2011  | "sum(amount) where value_x = colum name" for this specific day     |
+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------+----------------------+
```

Most obvious solution is:

```
SELECT SUM(amount), DATE(created) FROM `table_name` WHERE value_x=$some_variable GROUP BY DATE(created)
```

And loop this query six times with another value for `$some_variable` in every iteration, but I'm courious if is it possible to do this in single query?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943496/transpose-rows-into-columns-in-mysql

Comment: An easier solution would be not to store your data in this way.  If `one`, `two`, `three` etc. all represent the same data, they should be in the same field.

Comment: The question identified isn't a duplicate. That's about GROUP_CONCAT and this is a pivot table.

Comment: I suggest you look for "crosstab" or "pivot" for mysql. This could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking is called a "pivot table" and is typically achieved as below.  The idea is for each potential value of `value_x` you either produce a 1 or 0  per row and sum 1's and 0's to get the sum for each value.

```
SELECT
  DATE(created),
  SUM(CASE WHEN value_x = 'one' THEN SUM(amount) ELSE 0 END) AS 'one',
  SUM(CASE WHEN value_x = 'one' THEN SUM(amount) ELSE 0 END) AS 'two',
  SUM(CASE WHEN value_x = 'one' THEN SUM(amount) ELSE 0 END) AS 'three',
  etc...
FROM table_name
GROUP BY YEAR(created), MONTH(created), DAY(created)
```

Comment: +1, but the OP is asking for the sum(amount). So it should be `CASE value_x WHEN 'one' THEN SUM(amount) as one, WHEN 'two' THEN SUM(amount) as two ....`

Comment: First version was very helpfull too. Thanks, works like charm :)

Answer (score 1):

This will come close:

```
SELECT
   s.day_of_month
   ,GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(s.value_x,':',s.amount) ORDER BY s.value_x ASC) as output
   FROM (
         SELECT DATE(created) as day_of_month
                ,value_x
                ,SUM(amount) as amount
         FROM table1
         GROUP BY day_of_month, value_x
         ) s
GROUP BY s.day_of_month
```

You will need to read the output and look for the `value_x` prior to the `:` to place the items in the proper column.

The benefit of this approach over @Michael's approach is that you do not need to know the possible values of field `value_x` beforehand.