# Using group_concat how to iterate each value as a column

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic-sql

I am using MySQL.

I want to be able to always return 1 row with 5 columns on my query. I have a student table and a committee table as follows:

### Student Info Table

```
Student_Number    Committee_Id
00000001                5
```

### Committee Table

```
Committee Id         Prof_Id
    5                   23
    5                   55
    5                    6
    5                   10
```

Using this statement:

```
select committee_id, group_concat(prof_id) as profs from committee_table
```

I get:

```
profs        committee_id
23,55,6,10       5
```

I want to return:

```
prof1 prof2 prof3 prof4 prof5
23     55    6     10     null
```

Is there any way to do this simply?????

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4943496/1190388)

Comment: I changed my question to build on using group_concat

Comment: why do you want to display those items in a single row?

Comment: I need them for a report where I don't have much editing ability so if I could grab them they way they need to end up then I will be saving a lot of issues later.

Answer (score 0):

how about you try creating your committee table like this:

```
create table committee(committee_id datatype,prof1 datatype,prof2 datatype,prof3 datatype,prof4 datatype,prof5 datatype);
```

since the number of professors are static.

Comment: They are static in the sense that there is a max of 5 allowed but sometimes people just have 1. I didn't want to waste table space but that might be what I have to do.