# how to show values in database to be column header in reportviewer c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I want the data in the database to become the column header names by retrieving data from a table. This table has two fields, TimingID and Timing, I want to display the Timing as Column header in the reportviewer. Actually I am creating a schedule which shows the timing as the column so as to slot employees inside their respective timing. I want all the Timing to be displayed as a header. I wanted the Report to look like this.

```
LocationStation | 0000 | 0100 | 0200 | 0300 | 0400 | 0500 | 0600 | 0700 | 0800 | 0900 | 1000 | 1100 | 1200
T5-PML          | John | John | John | John | John | John | John | John | John | John | John | John
```

So it means that the employee, 'John' works from 00:00 to 12:00. The Timing stores all the time slot as shown at the column header. I want to show it like that.

Please give me some ideas of how to write in SQL statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use an expression for the column header...without more information how could we possibly help you?

Comment: Seems like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943496/transpose-rows-into-columns-in-mysql might be akin to what you are trying to do