# mysql, transpose/pivot row to column, variable selects

Tags: mysql, variables, pivot, transpose

Hello again  and thank you in advance for your help.

I've checked a few prior questions and couldn't find this exact situation.

I'm trying to transpose/pivot a row to column, but the results are based on a date function in the where clause, making my selects somewhat variable.

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(packet_details.installDate,'%m-%d-%Y') as Install_Date,
Count(packet_details.installDate)
FROM
packet_details
WHERE
 packet_details.installDate >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY
 AND packet_details.installDate "*lessthan*" CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 7 DAY
GROUP BY installDate
*lessthan symbol wont show here on Stack & i don't know how to fix it
```

Not sure if that makes sense so I included a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b235/3/0
So something like this:

```
INSTALL_DATE     COUNT
1/24/2013         2
1/25/2013         2
1/26/2013         2
1/27/2013         2
1/28/2013         2
1/29/2013         1
2/3/2013          1
2/4/2013          1
2/5/2013          5
2/6/2013          4
```

Turned into:

```
INSTALL_DATE    1/24/2013   1/25/2013   1/26/2013   1/27/2013   1/28/2013....   
COUNT             2             2          2             2         2               1
```

Comment: Do you need a SQL-only solution? Or some PHP (or other language) could help?

Comment: Possible duplicate: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943496/transpose-rows-into-columns-in-mysql>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943496/transpose-rows-into-columns-in-mysql</a>

Comment: Thank you Oscar, for now I'm looking for sql only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  Install_DATE,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Install_DATE = '01-24-2013' THEN totalCount END) `01-24-2013`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Install_DATE = '01-25-2013' THEN totalCount END) `01-25-2013`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Install_DATE = '01-26-2013' THEN totalCount END) `01-26-2013`,
        .......
FROM
(
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(packet_details.installDate,'%m-%d-%Y') as Install_Date,
         Count(packet_details.installDate) totalCount
  FROM   packet_details
  WHERE  packet_details.installDate >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND 
         packet_details.installDate   < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 7 DAY
  GROUP  BY installDate
) s
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b235/6)

For unknown number of `Install_Date`, a *Dynamic Query* is much preferred,

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN Install_DATE = ''',
      Install_Date,
      ''' then totalCount end) AS `', Install_Date, '`' )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM 
(
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(packet_details.installDate,'%m-%d-%Y') as Install_Date,
         Count(packet_details.installDate) totalCount
  FROM   packet_details
  WHERE  packet_details.installDate >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND 
         packet_details.installDate   < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 7 DAY
  GROUP  BY installDate
) s;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Install_DATE, ', @sql, ' 
                    FROM
                    (
                      SELECT DATE_FORMAT(packet_details.installDate,''%m-%d-%Y'') as Install_Date,
                             Count(packet_details.installDate) totalCount
                      FROM   packet_details
                      WHERE  packet_details.installDate >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND 
                             packet_details.installDate   < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 7 DAY
                      GROUP  BY installDate
                    ) s');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b235/10)

Comment: Thank you JW, looking forward to trying out the dynamic query, will report back.

Comment: JW, thank you again, I see this working in the fiddle, but I can't get it to work in phpmyadmin. also is there a way to not include that "install_date" label in the first field, as it's reflecting a specific date.

Comment: I eventually did get this work thank you again, I think I just needed a restart!  I had another quick question. I created another fiddle with an amended and additional table. Could you please help me figure out how to replace the value in R2C1 with result of a where clause based on the relationship between userId in both tables. For instance, if we just wanted to show install dates of where userId =1 and display the name "Billy" in R2C1. I can't figure out where to change the select to reflect the name without breaking the query. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ff68/1