# How to change column values into rows values in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi to everyone,

I am working in xml feed parsing section.In my database table structure is shown like this:

[image: Display image]
Here my needs is every sponsor are placed in single row not in multiple columns. For example :

```
   bookmaker_quote      scommessatipo_quote       q_1     q_2    q_3

    PINNACLE              1x2                     6.47    4.31   1.60
    BETCLICK              1x2                     5.80    2.25   2.15
    PADDYPOWER            UNDER/OVER 3.5          1.36    3.25   -
```

I want to show **quotavalore_quote**   values comes under single rows

How to show above table format using mysql query?

**Updated**

i show using group concat

```
SELECT distinct(bookmaker_quote) as bb ,group_concat(quotavalore_quote) as aa  FROM `quote`  where id_odds=10
```

this is result for group concat

```
bb           aa 

PINNACLE    6.47,4.31,1.60,5.80,2.25,2.15,11.00,1.03,3.80,1.25...
```

I get only one sponsor values , but i need to get all sponsor values..How to get this.......Please guide me..

Comment: it called transposing, mysql has no built-in function for it, here are some links that should point you in the right direction: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619678/mysql-transpose-pivot-row-to-column-variable-selects), [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568228/how-to-transpose-mysql-table-rows-into-columns)

Answer (score 0):

You can turn rows into a column with **GROUP_CONCAT** function. Try with that.