# Show date as column alias

Tags: mysql

I have column like below.

[image: table]

I need the date as column alias like

```
02/1/2019, 02/2/2019, 02/3/2019, 02/5/2019, 02/6/2019 etc
```

Comment: Please explain your issue using text and not images and clarify in what context you need this and what you have tried. For instance what type is t.date?

Comment: T.date is stored as varchar?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson t. date is varchar

Comment: @P.Salmon t. date is varchar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql, transpose/pivot row to column, variable selects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619678/mysql-transpose-pivot-row-to-column-variable-selects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET @today = CURRENT_DATE(),
@day1 = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL -1 DAY),
@day2 = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL -2 DAY),
@day3 = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL -3 DAY),
@day4 = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL -4 DAY),
@day5 = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL -5 DAY),
@sql = concat("SELECT JRR_RESULT, COUNT(LEFT(JRR_RESULT,40)) AS 'Total Error 
Last 
5 Days'"
", sum(IF( DATE_FORMAT(CREATION_DATE,'%Y-%m-%d') = '" , @day1, "',1,0) ) AS 
'", 
@day1, "' "
", sum(IF( DATE_FORMAT(CREATION_DATE,'%Y-%m-%d') = '" , @day2, "',1,0) ) AS 
'", 
@day2, "' "
", sum(IF( DATE_FORMAT(CREATION_DATE,'%Y-%m-%d') = '" , @day3, "',1,0) ) AS 
'", 
@day3, "' "
", sum(IF( DATE_FORMAT(CREATION_DATE,'%Y-%m-%d') = '" , @day4, "',1,0) ) AS 
'", 
@day4, "' "
", sum(IF( DATE_FORMAT(CREATION_DATE,'%Y-%m-%d') = '" , @day5, "',1,0) ) AS 
'", 
@day5, "' "
" FROM your_table where DATE_FORMAT(CREATION_DATE,'%Y-%m-%d') >= '" , @day5, 
"' "
" Group by LEFT(JRR_RESULT,40)"); 

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert to date type first (STR_TO_DATE) and then back to string (DATE_FORMAT) in the wanted format

```
STR_TO_DATE(t.date, '%c/%e/%Y'), DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(tdate, '%c/%e/%Y'), '%m/%e/%Y')
```