# SQL Query to compare 2 rows and store the differences in variables C#?

Tags: c#, sql, variables, compare

I am currently working on a project that is looking at having a database that will store only 2 rows of data in it. This database will have new rows added to it all the time and the top row will be deleted when a new row is entered making sure there are always 2 rows.

What I am looking to do is to compare the top row of data and the bottom row of data and then store the data that is different in variables. I only want to store the data that is different from the bottom row as the top row will always be the oldest sets of data and I would no longer need to handle that.

I can do this all on the C# side but I was wondering if there is a way to do most of this on the SQL side of things? Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you're trying to do? This is incredibly difficult to follow and your descriptions are very vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the clearification, let assume this table:

```
create table temp_monitor(id int, stamp datetime, @newTemp1 float, @newTemp2 float)
```

then this stored procedure should do the trick

```
create proc updateTempMonitor(temp_oven_1 float, temp_oven_2 float)
as

-- save the values where about to replace
declare @id int, @t1 float, @t2 float
select top 1 @id = id, @t1 = temp_oven_1, @t2 = temp_oven_2 from temp_monitor order by stamp

-- update the oldest
update updateTempMonitor set temp_oven_1 = @newTemp1, temp_oven_2 = @newTemp2 where id = @id

-- return data to caller (c#)
select @t1, @t2
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the replies.

To clarify I am going to have say Row 1 & Row 2 in a database(Row 1 will always be the oldest set of data). Then when a new set of Data comes in it will get put into the database, first there will be a check to see if 2 rows exist and if they do Row 1 (Oldest Data) will get removed and the current Row 2 will become Row 1 and the new data getting entered will be Row 2.

When the new data is in Row 2 I want to do a comparison with Row 1 to see which columns of data have changed. Then I want to store the values from Row 2 for the columns that have the changes.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in both side C# and SQL,

SQL side you need to write SP or something which will return you  pivot with the diff in the form of column name and changed columns.

look here for more  . [SQL Rows to Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187460/sql-rows-to-columns)