# SQL Join Query - Group By / Aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, pivot, unpivot

I realise this question has been asked before in many forms but I am struggling to apply every answer I've found to my specific table. To start - straight to the details.

Table A has four columns (Unique ID, Number, Revision, Date). When executing a select * from A, the result set is as follows -

```
ID | Number | Revision | Date
------------------------------------
01 | 12345  | 1        | 01/01/2010
02 | 12345  | 2        | 01/04/2010
03 | 123    | 1        | 01/12/2010
04 | 1234   | 1        | 09/09/2012
05 | 12345  | 3        | 09/12/2012
```

I would like the dates for each Revision in a single row per Number, e.g. for Number 12345, the query would return

```
ID | Number | Revision | Date | Revision 2 | Revision 2 Date | Revision 3 | Revision 3 Date |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
01 | 12345  | 1 | 01/01/2010 |2  | 01/04/2010      | 3 |  09/12/2012|
```

I understand the syntax would be similar to

```
SELECT Revision, Date 
FROM (
SELECT NUMBER 
FROM A) as B INNER JOIN ON a.Number = B.Number 
GROUP BY a.Number
```

However this still returns a row for each combination, I would like only the results shown above.

I would appreciate any suggestions or hints!

Comment: you should not use the same colon name for two tables

Comment: Did you see this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187460/sql-rows-to-columns

Comment: Pivot is what you need to turn your Revisions and Dates into columns
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use both an `UNPIVOT` and then a `PIVOT` to accomplish this.  If you have a known number of values to convert to column, then you can use a STATIC `PIVOT` and hard-code the values:

```
select number, [revision_1], [date_1],
             [revision_2], [date_2],
             [revision_3], [date_3]
from
(
  select number, value,
    col + '_' + cast(rn as varchar(10)) col
  from
  (
    select id, number, cast(revision as varchar(10)) revision, 
      convert(varchar(10), date, 120) date,
      row_number() over(partition by number order by date) rn
    from yourtable
  ) x
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (revision, date)
  ) u
) x1
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in ([revision_1], [date_1],
             [revision_2], [date_2],
             [revision_3], [date_3])
)p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67d11/9)

If you have an unknown number of values, then you will need to use dynamic SQL to `PIVOT` the data.

```
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot as  NVARCHAR(MAX)


select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT  ',' 
                      + quotename(c.name + '_'
                         + cast(t.rn as varchar(10)))
                    from
                    (
                      select row_number()
                        over(partition by number order by date) rn
                      from yourtable
                    ) t
                    cross apply 
                      sys.columns as C
                   where C.object_id = object_id('yourtable') and
                         C.name in ('Revision', 'date')
                   group by c.name, t.rn
                   order by t.rn
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query 
  = 'select *
      from
      (
          select number, value,
            col + ''_'' + cast(rn as varchar(10)) col
        from 
        (
          select id, number, cast(revision as varchar(10)) revision, 
            convert(varchar(10), date, 120) date,
            row_number() over(partition by number order by date) rn
          from yourtable
        ) x
        unpivot
        (
          value
          for col in (revision, date)
        ) u
      ) x1
      pivot
      (
        max(value)
        for col in ('+ @colspivot +')
      ) p'

exec(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle With demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67d11/21)

Comment: Excellent! Thank-you, one issue though, every date is null, when I run select convert(varchar(10), date, 120) date from mytable, the dates are fine, however in both of those queries (the second dynamic one, there is no date columns at all) dates are all null.

Comment: @user1142132 can you create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with some sample data for me to look at?  Using your sample I did not get any null dates -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67d11/21

Comment: I've created an sqlfiddle to replicate my table and some sample data and I'm not getting the null dates in it http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8706a/1, however here's a screenshot of my results in sql server http://i.imgur.com/Qx4oN.png

Comment: @user1142132 can you create a larger data sample on the sql fiddle?  It is hard to tell with only two rows of data

Comment: apologies, I've added a few more, the dates still appear, let me know if you need a larger sample.

Comment: @user1142132 the larger the sample the better, once you add a new sample, please post the sql fiddle link here

Comment: @user1142132 I am not sure why it is displaying `null` values for you.  I would double check the query to be sure you have not included unneeded fields otherwise it will not be accurate.