# Sql server- convert row into column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I have a problem and can't find a way to solve it.

This is my part of my query that I cannot solve.

```
   Select Datepart(day,date) as Day, 
          Department,SUM(hourly) as workhours
     from MIVDb.dbo.evid as p 
     Inner Join MIVdb.dbo.workers as r 
        On p.rad=r.rad
    Group by Department,
             Datepart(day,date)
```

Nothing special about it. My problem is that I get table looking like

```
   Days   Dept     Hours
    1     Sales    8
    2     Cust     10
```

And i need:

```
     Dept   1  2 ....etc
     Sales  8 10 ....etc
```

So I need days to be columns. Problem is that Days column is dynamic, it can have on day, of 20 day, it can be week or even month. Can someone point help me with this.

Comment: http://sqlserveradvisor.blogspot.in/2009/03/sql-server-convert-rows-to-columns.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple way to transpose columns and rows in Sql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187460/sql-rows-to-columns

Comment: take a look at **Pivot** http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx