# Can I format results from SQL query like a Excel sheet

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I am running a query for every truck in our fleet to see the mileage and amount of fuel used over a month, quarter or year time frame. So my columns are Date, Truck, Miles. Formatting the results is time consuming because all the trucks' data are listed together like below.

```
   Date   Truck   Miles
   1/1/15   101     542
   1/2/15   101     342
```

Is there a way to format the query results when coping to Excel or running the query as a macro in Excel so the results are displayed like a 3d table like below?

```
   Truck  1/1/15  1/2/15  1/3/15
    101      542     342     741
    102      121     214     141
    103      541     741     874
```

Comment: You might want to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074939/get-rows-as-columns-sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query or this http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Rows to Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187460/sql-rows-to-columns)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query is probably what you want

Answer (score -2):

You have to create a stored procedure and cursor like this example below.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @au_id varchar(11),
 @au_fname varchar(20),
 @au_lname varchar(40),
 @message varchar(80),
 @title varchar(80)
PRINT('-------- Utah Authors report --------')
DECLARE authors_cursor CURSOR FOR
(SELECT au_id, au_fname, au_lname
FROM authors
WHERE state = 'UT'
ORDER BY au_id)
OPEN authors_cursor
FETCH FIRST FROM authors_cursor INTO @au_id, @au_fname, @au_lname
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   PRINT(' ')
   SET @message = '----- Books by Author: ' + @au_fname + ' ' + @au_lname
   PRINT(@message)
   -- Declare an inner cursor based
   -- on au_id from the outer cursor.
   DECLARE titles_cursor CURSOR FOR
   (SELECT t.title
   FROM titleauthor ta, titles t
   WHERE ta.title_id = t.title_id AND
   ta.au_id = @au_id)   -- Variable value from the outer cursor
   OPEN titles_cursor
   FETCH FIRST FROM titles_cursor INTO @title
   IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
      PRINT('         <<No Books>>')
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
      SET @message = '         ' + @title
      PRINT @message
      FETCH NEXT FROM titles_cursor INTO @title
   END
   CLOSE titles_cursor
   DEALLOCATE titles_cursor
   -- Get the next author.
   FETCH NEXT FROM authors_cursor INTO @au_id, @au_fname, @au_lnameEND
CLOSE authors_cursor
DEALLOCATE authors_cursor
GO
```

Comment: No no no, the answer would be to use PIVOT, either static or dynamic if the list of items can change. This example code that you copied from the [SQL Server 2000 Book Online](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258831%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) really has nothing to do with this at all.