# SQL, from , separated rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Create table test123
(
SeqId int,
string1 varchar(100),
string2 varchar(100)
)

insert into test123(SeqId,string1,string2)values
(10,'a,b,c','x,y,z'),
(20,'d,e,f','p,q,r')
```

output

```
SeqId RowNum String1 String2
10  1   a   x
10  2   b   y
10  3   c   z
20  1   d   p
20  2   e   q
20  3   f   r
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187460/sql-rows-to-columns

Comment: There are about a million and one ways to split comma-delimited strings. Look up literally any of them. e.g. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Comment: Lots of possible information missing here: Will the comma-delimited strings always have the same number of elements in both string1 and string2? Will they be the same number of elements between rows? Why would you want to store the data this way anyway? Inquiring and helpful minds want to know.

Comment: Perhaps use STRING_SPLIT, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will allow for a variable/uneven number of items within the string.

Just about any Split/Parse function will do.  I've supply one which also provides a sequence number of the item.

**Option 1: Without a Parse Function**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SeqId int,string1 varchar(100),string2 varchar(100))
insert into @YourTable values
(10,'a,b,c','x,y,z'),
(20,'d,e,f','p,q,r')

Select A.SeqId
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RowNum  = RetSeq
                      ,String1 = max(String1)
                      ,String2 = max(String2)
                 From (
                        Select RetSeq  = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                              ,String1 = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                              ,String2 = ''
                        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.String1,',','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                        Union All
                        Select RetSeq  = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                              ,String1 = ''
                              ,String2 = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.String2,',','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                      ) B1
                 Group By RetSeq
             ) B
```

**Option 2: With a Parse Function**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SeqId int,string1 varchar(100),string2 varchar(100))
insert into @YourTable values
(10,'a,b,c','x,y,z'),
(20,'d,e,f','p,q,r')

Select A.SeqId
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RowNum = RetSeq
                      ,String1= max(String1)
                      ,String2= max(String2)
                 From (
                        Select RetSeq,String1=RetVal,String2='' from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.string1,',')
                        Union All
                        Select RetSeq,String1='',String2=RetVal from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.string2,',')
                      ) B1
                 Group By RetSeq

             ) B
```

**Both Return**

[image]

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(25))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d) A ),
           cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter),
           cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By A.N)
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(Substring(@String, A.N, A.L)))
    From   cte4 A
);
--Orginal Source http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('John||Cappelletti||was||here','||')
```

Comment: Worked like a gem, really helped me a lot. I know how to do it when it is just one column, for more than one column your solution works great.

Comment: @SrinivasaRao Happy it helped

Answer (score 0):

Check below solution using dynamic SQL

```html
declare @t table (SeqId int, string1 varchar(100), string2 varchar(100))

declare @result table(SeqId int, RowNum int, String1 varchar(10), String2 varchar(10))

declare @SeqId int

declare @string1 varchar(100)

declare @string2 varchar(100)

declare @char1 varchar(5)

declare @char2 varchar(5)

declare @count1 int

declare @count2 int

declare @rownum int


insert into @t select * from test123

while exists (select * from @t)
begin

select top 1 @SeqId = SeqId, @string1 = string1, @string2 = string2 from @t

set @rownum = 1

while @rownum <=3
begin

set @count1 = charindex(',',@string1,1) - 1

if @count1 < 0
 set @count1 = len(@string1)

set @count2 = charindex(',',@string2,1) - 1

if @count2 < 0
 set @count2 = len(@string2)

set @char1 = substring(@string1, 1, @count1)

set @char2 = substring(@string2, 1, @count2)

insert into @result values(@SeqId, @rownum, @char1, @char2)

set @string1 = substring(@string1, charindex(',',@string1,1)+1, len(@string1)-charindex(',',@string1,1))

set @string2 = substring(@string2, charindex(',',@string2,1)+1, len(@string2)-charindex(',',@string2,1))

set @rownum = @rownum + 1

end

delete top (1) from @t
end

select * from @result
```