# Selecting Dates From a table as Column Headers

Tags: sql, sqlite

i have a Table like this

```
ID  Date        Product_id       Inventory

1   2/1/2017       1             180

2   9/1/2017       1             167

3   16/1/2017      1             320

4   23/1/2017      1             500

5   30/1/2017      1             20
```

How to write a SQL query on the table above to fetch a result like below

```
product_id    2/1/2017    9/1/2017    16/1/2017    23/1/2017    30/1/2017 ....

  1             180         167        320           50            20
```

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187460/sql-rows-to-columns?s=2|3.7334